# How can I update my tkinter game only when there is a click event?

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm trying to make a game and I want to update the `rungame()` only after the `mouseClickHandler` was used.

and this is what I did in `runGame()`:

```
 def runGame():
    global i,update,scoreDraw,questionA

    setInitialValues()
    drawObjects()

    if update == True:

        questionAsk()
        canvas.update()
        i += 1
        updateObjects()
        checkForCollisions()
        canvas.delete(scoreDraw,questionA)
        canvas.update()
```

and this is what `runGame()` does:

```
def setInitialValues():
    global score, time, update, worldGIF


    score = 0
    time = 0
    update = True
    worldGIF = PhotoImage(file = "WorldMap.gif")

def drawObjects():

    global worldMap,scoreStart,questionAA

    worldMap = canvas.create_image(650, 400, image = worldGIF)
    scoreStart = canvas.create_text(500,600,text=score, font= 'Times 24', anchor = W, fill = "white")
    questionAA = canvas.create_text(400,700, text="Hello!", font= "Times 20", anchor = W,fill = "white")
    canvas.update()

def questionAsk():
    global x_coord, y_coord, country, question, i
    global question
    question = "Where is", country[i],"?"

def updateObjects():
    global scoreDraw, questionA
    roundScore = round(score)
    scoreDraw = canvas.create_text(500,600,text=roundScore, font= 'Times 24', anchor = W, fill = "white")
    questionA = canvas.create_text(400,700, text=question, font= "Times 20", anchor = W,fill = "white")
    canvas.update()

def mouseClickHandler( event ):
    global i, xMouse,yMouse,answerx,answery,score,distance,update
    canvas.delete(scoreStart,questionAA)
    xMouse = event.x
    yMouse = event.y
    answerx = x_coord[i]
    answery = y_coord[i]
    delta_x = abs(xMouse - answerx)
    delta_y = abs(yMouse - answery)
    distance = sqrt((delta_x)**2+(delta_y)**2)
    score = score + distance
    update = True
```

But it never updates, for some reason, it just doesn't detect the `update = True` statement in the `mouseClickHandler`.

Extras:

`x_coord, y_coord, country` are all numpy  arrays which I have made earlier and imported into here. `worldGIF` is just a picture of a map.

So tldr; I can't find a way to trigger the `if update == True` part in `runGame()` only where there is a Click.

These binds at the bottom:

```
root.after( 0, runGame )

canvas.bind( "<Button-1>", mouseClickHandler )

canvas.bind( "<Key>", keyDownHandler )

canvas.bind( "<KeyRelease>", keyUpHandler )

canvas.pack()

canvas.focus_set()
```

Comment: Is `mouseClickHandler` being called in the first place? Where is your `mainloop()` call (or manual event loop)? It looks like you're just starting up the GUI and then not doing anything to process events, so nothing you do (including clicks) will have any effect.

Comment: Meanwhile, `if` statements don't "trigger" when their conditions become true. They just check whether their conditions are true, when you evaluate them. If you want that check to happen after every click, you have to move the `if` block into the click handler.

Comment: @abarnert sorry, I didn't provide enough information. I have mouseClickHandler bonded as `canvas.bind("<Button-1>", mouseClickHandler)` . It runs whenever there is a click on the tkinter screen. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `runGame` to run on every mouse click, you're going to need to call it in `mouseClickHandler` (assuming that function is bound to a click event)

For example:

```
canvas.bind("<1>", runGame)

def mouseClickHandler( event ):
    global i, xMouse,yMouse,answerx,answery,score,distance,update
    ...
    update = True
    runGame()
```

### However, ...

My guess is that you don't want `runGame` to run on every click, but only the code in the `if` block. If that's true, move that code to a separate block and call it from `mouseClickHander`, and eliminate the use of the `update` variable.

For example:

```
def runGame():
    global i,scoreDraw,questionA
    setInitialValues()
    drawObjects()
    updateGame()

def updateGame():
    global i

    questionAsk()
    canvas.update()
    i += 1
    updateObjects()
    checkForCollisions()
    canvas.delete(scoreDraw,questionA)
    canvas.update()

def mouseClickHandler( event ):
    global i, xMouse,yMouse,answerx,answery,score,distance
    canvas.delete(scoreStart,questionAA)
    ...
    score = score + distance
    updateGame()
```